# No route matches "/userhome/18/edit_reviewer_email"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

The test line that i set up in the controller is not printing in the console... so the action is going back to edit_reviewer_email without following the defined route. Here is the code.

edit_reviewer_email:

```
<%= form_for :user, @user, update_reviewer_email_userhome_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= f.submit "Update Email" %>
<% end %>
```

warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using form_for(:name, @resource) is deprecated. Please use form_for(@resource, :as => :name) instead.
```

userhome_controller:

```
  def update_reviewer_email
   p "***" # test line
   @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to(root_path, :notice => 'Email was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit_reviewer_email" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

error:

```
No route matches "/userhome/18/edit_reviewer_email"
```

route:

```
  resources :userhome, :except => [:show, :new, :edit, :update, :destroy]  do
    member do
      get :edit_reviewer_email
      post :update_reviewer_email
    end
  end
```

rake routes:

```
update_reviewer_email_userhome POST   /userhome/:id/update_reviewer_email(.:format) {:action=>"update_reviewer_email", :controller=>"userhome"}
```

log file:

```
Started POST "/userhome/18/edit_reviewer_email" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-15 09:36:52 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/userhome/18/edit_reviewer_email"):

Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.7ms)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try to change your `form_for` ? Also please post a chunk of code from log file

Comment: @BohdanPohorilets, no... the form_for code is the same as above. Thought i would worry about the deprecation warning after i got the rest of the problem addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you have

```
<%= form_for :user, @user, update_reviewer_email_userhome_path do |f| %>
```

which should do a POST request to `/userhome/18/update_reviewer_email` however in log you have

```
Started POST "/userhome/18/edit_reviewer_email"
```

that obviously doesn't match any of your routes to fix it please try change your form to

```
<%= form_for :user, @user, :url => update_reviewer_email_userhome_path do |f| %>
```